# Latest compatible version of hadoop and hbase

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, compatibility

I have to install hadoop and hbase on 4 machines.
 I have found latest version of **`hadoop-2.6.0 and hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2-bin`**.

1)Are they compatible?
2)How I should install hbase and hadoop on 4 machines i.e. how many masters and slaves etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering your questions :

1. See the Hbase-Hadoop compatibility [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop) . hbase-0.98.9 should support hadoop-2.6.0.
2. You have two options

   - 1 master node and 3 slave nodes. (Since you have only 4 nodes this
     configuration would be suffice)
   - If you wanted to enabled HA, you can go for 2 master nodes and 2 slave nodes.

Comment: In given link, there is no information about hadoop-2.6.0?

Comment: In the given link there is no hbase version to support hadoop-2.6.0.

Comment: Does any version of hbase support hadoop-2.6.0 atm?

Answer (score 6):

Considering the first question, I was trying to find the answer myself and found this in [hbase docs](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop):

- "S" = supported
- "X" = not supported
- "NT" = Not tested

[image]