# How do i set up HBase with HDFS 3.1.0?

Tags: hbase, hdfs, version, hadoop3

HDFS 2.7 is default version for HBase 2.0.0. 
For HBase Stable version, it is, 2.5.
I just started HDFS cluster with version 3.1.0. How do I make HBase to use this? 
I get hsync error message.

EDIT

I am understanding that I have to replace all these jar files? 
hadoop-*-2.7.4.jar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WcYR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [Latest compatible version of hadoop and hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798014/latest-compatible-version-of-hadoop-and-hbase) then follow the link provided which is http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#configuration you will see that your combination is not supported yet.

[image]

(`NT` stands for "Not Tested").

You can also track Hadoop 3 compatibility by watching JIRA HBASE-20540.

- [[umbrella] Hadoop 3 compatibility](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-20540)

Comment: Thank you. if I use Hbase 2.0 and wants to use Hadoop 2.8.3, which is supported, how do i change default hadoop version 2.7 to 2.8.3?

Comment: Is this the part that I have to do? Where do i find my hadoop jar files? I couldn't find it. `replace the hadoop jars found in the HBase lib directory with the equivalent hadoop jars from the version you are running on your cluster to avoid version mismatch issues.`

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html should provide a link to the binaries you need.