# HBase-testing-util: All datanodes are bad error on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, testing, hbase

I'm trying to use hbase-testing-util (1.2.0) on my project, but i get the following error:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: All datanodes 127.0.0.1:54655 are bad. Aborting...
```

I'm using IntelliJ on Windows 10, and I've correctly setup HADOOP_HOME environment variable.

I read that property mapred.max.split.size could help me, but i don't know which file I have to modify.

Comment: Do you have a datanode running on your host?

Comment: No. On Windows OS i've only the IDE and the Hadoop binaries. I've also put hbase-testing-util in pom.xml of my project.

Comment: It won't work unless you run Hadoop (all daemons) in addition to all the services HBase needs.

Comment: I've installed Hadoop on Windows that it's up and running... but i get the same error. Do you know how to set the datanode port in HBaseTestingUtility() definition?

Comment: Which version of Hadoop?  Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221379/how-do-i-set-up-hbase-with-hdfs-3-1-0/ for a reference.

Comment: HBase 1.2.0 and Hadoop 2.7.3: this combination is supported. Do you have a code example?

Comment: `dfs.datanode.address`, `dfs.datanode.http.address`, and  `dfs.datanode.ipc.address` should be defined in your hdfs-site.xml.  See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml as this shows the defaults.