# Classes not found with Hadoop 3.0.0 alpha onward releases

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In integration testing of my hBase based application iam using hbaseTestingUtil. In my dependency i have hadoop common and hadoop hdfs, upto 2.9.0 version everything was but after 3.0.0 release my facing classes not found errors like DistributedFileSystem , MiniCluster etc

Comment: Hbase doesn't support Hadoop 3.x, and has limited support for 2.9 last time I checked HBase site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i set up HBase with HDFS 3.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221379/how-do-i-set-up-hbase-with-hdfs-3-1-0)